# what is the word to describe such an expression?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

When we chat on the internet we use expressions like “Hey, it’s so good to hear from you” even though we are not speaking to or hearing each other. What is the word used to describe this kind of expression?

I know there is a word, but I can’t seem to remember it.

Comment: I'd call it a "greeting".  But it's an idiom as well.  (Though one wonders where you perceive the expression if you are not speaking or hearing it.)

Comment: Have you checked the various meanings of *hear* in a good dictionary?

Comment: *hear*: "**2.2** [no object] (hear from) Be contacted by (someone), especially by letter or telephone: *if you would like to join the committee, we would love to hear from you*" ODO http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hear

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you're using the word 'hear' *figuratively* or *metaphorically*.

But perhaps you're asking about the more specific and very common case of using 'hear' when you are not literally speaking / listening. I don't know if there's a term for that.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @Ik-'s answer, both which are good words, you could use "figure of speech" or "standard greeting".